# Why is Magnetic field given as ampere per metre? What does ampere have to do here?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, dimensional-analysis, si-units

Isn't it just 1 coulomb of electrons passing any cross section per second? Why is it involved here in magnetism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ToAmpere's law can be written (for static fields)
$$\oint \vec{H}\cdot d\vec{l} = I_{\rm enc}\ ,$$
where $\vec{H}$ is the "magnetic field", which is integrated around a closed path, and $I_{\rm enc}$ is the current enclosed by that path.

From this equation it is clear that the H-field has units of A/m (in SI units).

It seems quite likely that you have become confused between the B-field (magnetic flux density, which is often called the magnetic field and has SI units of Tesla) and the H-field (also often called the magnetic field or magnetic field intensity), which has units of A/m.

Answer (score 0):

The Biot-Savart law for a steady current gives the magnetic field as follows:
$$\vec B(\vec r) = \dfrac{μ_0}{4π}\int\dfrac{(\vec I \times(\vec r - \vec r'))}{(\vec r - \vec r')^3}dl$$
Since $\vec I$ is in amperes, $\vec r$ and $\vec r'$ ar in meters, you get that unit for magnetic field

Comment: Welcome! This answer (v1) assumes a system of units where $\mu_0$ is dimensionless, but in SI that constant has dimension tesla-meter/ampere.

Comment: It is  the field H, not the field B, which is measured in A/m in SI units.